# encoding a url to retrieve it in php

Tags: php, mysql, variables, encoding

I'm creating sort of car-configurator webapp.

I want to derive a unique flag (string) representing a URL, which i'll store in a DB and then i'll send it though mail to the people that uses my app.

Then, if the user comes back to the website, from the home page, he can retrieve his last configuration with that flag.

Main problem is that I'm super new to PHP and I don't know hot to automatic generate a little string associated to a variable (the variable is the page url).

in short i need to do something like that:

```
$url = "www.some-domain.com?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3&foo=4";
```

i need to transform that `$url` into something like this `xr0314r`.
And this string it must be unique and auto-generated.

Someone can pass me a valid example? or put me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's currently not very clear what you're trying to achieve. What is the relationship between the URL you showed and the string xr0314r?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: hi @Utkanos, i simply need to transform the url into a string (that string actually is only for example).
So, in another page i've a simple form in witch a user can inser the string and retrieve the page.
i know that a user can directly copy the url, but sometimes that url is very long and i prefer to encode it to simplify the URL

Comment: But what is the relationship between the URL and the string? Do you mean you just want to derive a unique flag (string) representing a URL, which you'll store in a DB or something? Otherwise, how does one translate from the string to the URL?

Comment: hi @Utkanos, yes,  I want to derive a unique flag (string) representing a URL, which you'll store in a DB and then send it though mail to the people that uses my app. Then, if the user comes back to the website, from the home page, he can retrieve his last configuration with that flag.

Comment: That's a very broad question - better to break it into chunks. Your first step is to generate a random string. [Lots of examples](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=php+generate+random+string&addon=firefox&addonversion=4.0.4) of that.

Comment: Thank for your patience @Utkanos, the main problem is to generate the random string associated with a variable.
I know how to insert it into a DB (that I already have) and then I already know how to send it via email to the user.

other part that I miss, is to decode the string from the home page when the user insert the string into the form to retrieve the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've understood there's not really any en/decoding going on here. You seem to just want to derive a flag for a full URL, save that to a DB, and allow a user to later enter that flag into a form to retrieve (and presumably go to) the saved URL.

With which in mind, first let's generate a string. There's any number of ways of doing this, but here's a simple example:

```
function derive_flag() {
    $flag_len = 6;
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
    $ret = '';
    //iteratively build the flag, with a random character from $chars
    for($f=0; $f<$flag_len; $f++) $ret .= substr($chars, rand(0, strlen($chars)-1), 1);
    return $ret;
}
echo derive_flag(); //e.g. "ax9sb9"
```

You then save that to your DB, against the current URL. So your lookup table might be called `urls` and look like:

```
-------------------
| id | flag | url |
-------------------
```

and be populated like

```
---------------------------------
| id | flag   | url             |
---------------------------------
| 1  | ah69vm | https://foo.bar |
---------------------------------
```

Then when the user needs to retrieve the URL from a flag, you just have a form which looks up in that DB. I'll assume for this example that `flag` is being sent in a POST field from the form. Obviously you'd need to do some form validation, to check that the flag was submitted.

```
//$db is your DB connection via new mysqli()
if ($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT url FROM urls WHERE flag = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['flag']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($url);
    $stmt->fetch();
    //URL now lives in $url - print it out, go to it, whatever
    $stmt->close();
}
```

(FYI, if that DB code looks weird, it's an example of using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). It's a good technique for secure DB transactions, e.g. to avoid SQL injection.)

Comment: That's what i need! and it's more simpler than what i thought!
Thank you very much!